# Multiple node apps in sub folders

Tags: node.js, express, vhosts

I want to create a site with this structure:

```
--mysite.com   
--mainserver.js  
-----mysite.com/project1  
-----server.js  
-----mysite.com/project2  
-----server.js
```

In each project folder I want to run a separate node application. Im trying to do this using [vhost](https://www.npmjs.org/package/vhost) module.
In my mainserver.js I have this to test:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var router = express.Router();
var vhost = require('vhost');

var app2 = express();
    app2.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send("echo");
    });
app.use(vhost('localhost/project1', app2));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("hi");
});

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port, function() {
  //console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

When navigating to localhost:8000 I see the "hi". But when I navigate to localhost:8000/project1 I get `Cannot GET /test`...
Please help!

Comment: Is there a reason you want multiple Express apps rather than using  Routers?

Comment: I want to be able to do "clean" projects for learning stuff. Of course I could keep all in one server.js file but it would become huge after a while. Or am I missing something? :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to achieve. (Without use of vhost)

**project1/index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  return res.send('project 1');
});

// Other routes specific to project 1 here

module.exports = router;
```

Project2 could be set up similarly.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/project1', require('./project1'));

app.use('/project2', require('./project2'));

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.listen(port);
```

Comment: oh! ok. hmm. But lets say I want project1 to have login and use some packages and have different configs. Could I achieve to?

Comment: You can isolate middleware and routes with this method. You'll have to be more specific.